How to retrive the column in a text using pyspark
I have a text file data like this,
Name|age|course|"A"|20|"Science"|"B"|23|"Math"|"C"|25|"Englsih"

I need to get the columns Name, age, and Course and I have to a create data frame. please any one help me with this problem.
I tried this code
df = spark.read.csv("test.txt")

df_split = df.withColumn("split_data", split(df["_col"], "\\|"))

df_final = df_split.select(
    col("split_data")[0].alias("Name"),
    col("split_data")[1].alias("Age"),
    col("split_data")[2].alias("Course")
)

df_final.show()

is your data is in one line or multiple lines ?

only single line

what is the output you are expected ?

my expected output is : +----+---+-------+
|name|age|course |
+----+---+-------+
|A   |20 |Science|
|B   |23 |Math   |
|C   |25 |Englsih|
+----+---+-------+

You can check below solution which is giving exact your expected output

spark.read.csv(filepath, sep='|')
The file that you given as example is a text file in which all the columns are separated using "|" (pipe) symbol , in practice we generally see flat text files having ","(comma) as the separator. To deal such peculiar text separators spark provides an option of providing the sep parameter in the function call we can leverage the same to get the data parsed correctly.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

@EsmaeelE: It does offer an answer. It’s just not an especially good answer without additional explanation or details to help readers out.

I have added a proper explanation

Check below code.
from pyspark.sql.functions import F

num_cols = 3 # Number of columns in data
schema = "name string, age string, course string" # Schema of data

df
.show(5, False) # Printing original data

+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|input                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|Name|age|course|"A"|20|"Science"|"B"|23|"Math"|"C"|25|"Englsih|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

df
.withColumn(
  "ins", 
  F.expr("split(input, '[|]')") # Split the data using '|'
)
.withColumn(
  "size", 
  F.expr("size(data)") # size of the split column
)
.withColumn(
  "rows",
  F.expr(f"filter(sequence({num_cols},size,{num_cols}), (s, i) -> i <> 0)") # Skipping header
)
.withColumn(
  "data", 
  F.expr(f"transform(rows, f -> concat_ws(',',slice(ins, f-{num_cols}+1, {num_cols})))") 
) # Extract rows except header
.selectExpr(f"inline(transform(data, o -> from_csv(o, '{schema}')))") # Applying schema to every row using from_csv & schema
.show(5, False)

+----+---+-------+
|name|age|course |
+----+---+-------+
|A   |20 |Science|
|B   |23 |Math   |
|C   |25 |Englsih|
+----+---+-------+

